# Android / OpenGL glRotatef has no perspective when using GLOrthof

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, android-canvas

I'm writing a game that is basically 2D, what i need is to have a scene with simple coordinates to emulate something like the Android Canvas, so 0,0 is top left and w/h are bottom right. Up to now i have been able to create the scene and draw to it, everything works properly, translate moves the objects correctly according to w/h coordinates in my 2D plane.

Problem is that now i want to "flip" a texture using X axis rotation and i want a 3D effect while flipping, if i use the "rotatef" call the flip occurs but its flat, so there is no perspective at all, is just like scaling the height till it goes to zero so there is no distance perception.

I currently create the ViewPort in this way:

```
gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glOrthof(0, w, h, 0, -1f, 100f);
gl.glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

This will create my desired viewport with 0/0 at top left and w/h at bottom right filling the screen. Then i load my texture from a Bitmap.

```
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
```

And finally i draw the texture:

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glPushMatrix();
// Translate to starting position first in 0,0,w,h coordinates
gl.glTranslatef(mXOffset, mYOffset, 0f);
// Rotate 45 degrees on X axis
gl.glRotatef(45, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
// Draw
gl.glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, sVertexBuffer);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, mTextureBuffer);
gl.glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
gl.glPopMatrix();
```

Finally my vertex buffers are:

```
float vertices[] = {
        0f, 0f,  // 0, Top Left
        0f, 1f,  // 1, Bottom Left
        1f, 0f,  // 3, Top Right
        1f, 1f,  // 2, Bottom Right
};
float texturePoints[] = {
        0f, 0f,
        0f, v,
        u, 0,
        u, v,
};
```

Is this caused by the Ortho call? I have tried to obtain a similar result with GLU but there is no way i can replicate this easy coordinate system and i am hardly able to draw something.

Answer (score 0):

An orthographic projection will not give you perspective since it just projects the vertices in a straight line towards the camera. Instead of `gl.glOrthof` you should use `GLU.gluPerspective`, if it is possible to do this only while flipping the texture.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLU.html

Comment: In understand however the question is how i can obtain the same result without Orthof, so, how can i have a similar viewport with 0,0,w,h covering the full screen using gluPerspective instead of Ortho? I tried many combinations but i cannot get anything working.